# Get "id" value from httpget json response

Tags: json

Below is my JSON output received post the HttpGet successful execution.

```
{
    "results": [{
        "id": "1310760",
        "type": "page",
        "status": "current",
        "title": "UniversalProfile Release Test",
        "extensions": {
            "position": 9
        },
        "_links": {
            "webui": "/display/ds/UniversalProfile+Release+Test",
            "tinyui": "/x/KAAU",
            "self": "http:1310760"
        },
        "_expandable": {
            "container": "/rest/api/space/ds",
            "metadata": "",
            "operations": "",
            "children": "/rest/api/content/1310760/child",
            "history": "/rest/api/content/1310760/history",
            "ancestors": "",
            "body": "",
            "version": "",
            "descendants": "/rest/api/content/1310760/descendant",
            "space": "/rest/api/space/ds"
        }
    }],
    "start": 0,
    "limit": 25,
    "size": 1,
    "_links": {
        "self": "UniversalProfile+Release+Test",
        "base": "https://alim4azad.atlassian.net/wiki",
        "context": "/wiki"
    }
}
```

I am trying to extract the value for "id" but have been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: Please format your JSON so it is readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a solution for it . Below is the solution.

```
    JSONArray results = getbodyPage.getJSONArray("results");
    JSONObject first = results.getJSONObject(0);
    Long id = first.getLong("id"); // Get id of the found page
    System.out.println("INFO : Found ID - " + id);
```

Thank you all for your valuable inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using JavaScript, try this: `output.results[0]['id']`

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON is in the variable `output` in Javascript, it'd be :

```
output.results[0]["id"]
```

Like `console.log(output.results[0]["id"])`.

Your `results` section contains arrays.   You want the first (0), and then the key `id`.

Looking at that resulting JSON hurts my brain.

Answer (score 0):

> Try This:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("id");
```